# torch.inverse returns identity matrices. Bug resolved by print input before calculation (But why?)

Tags: python, multithreading, printing, pytorch

torch.inverse() only returns identity matrices. (see *unnormal output* below). It occur repeatly after the first iteration.

If I try to print anything of `pose_pre` first, the problem would disapear. (see *normal output* below)

Here is a part of the code:

```py
    # print(pose_pre) # <--------if I add this line, the bug would be gone
    pose_pre_inv = torch.inverse(pose_pre)
    print(pose_pre_inv)
```

#### why would the first print line affect result

#### Any ideas would be appreciated!

ps.
`pose_pre = pose3d_BT[:,:-1,...].reshape(-1,4,4)`. The `pose3d_BT` is provided by the `__getitem__` function in pytorch. I printed the content in `__getitem__` and it looks normal.

---

---

## unnormal output with `eye(4)`

```
tensor([[[ 8.7334e-01, -4.8659e-01,  2.2528e-02,  6.4885e+03],                                          | 0/90 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
         [ 4.8635e-01,  8.7363e-01,  1.5527e-02, -4.6202e+03],
         [-2.7237e-02, -2.6037e-03,  9.9963e-01, -6.3445e+01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]],

        [[ 8.7334e-01, -4.8659e-01,  2.2528e-02,  6.4885e+03],
         [ 4.8635e-01,  8.7363e-01,  1.5527e-02, -4.6202e+03],
         [-2.7237e-02, -2.6037e-03,  9.9963e-01, -6.3445e+01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]]],
       device='cuda:0'),)
saving hidden-state image hc_state_14_31_18_734196.png to ../../visual_result/lstm_hidden_states
epochs:   0%|                                                                      | 0/1 [00:01<?, ?it/s, loss=4.14, lr=0.0003](tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0.],                                                         | 1/90 [00:01<01:49,  1.23s/it, total_it=1]
         [0., 1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 1.]],

        [[1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 1.]]], device='cuda:0'),)
saving hidden-state image hc_state_14_31_19_915028.png to ../../visual_result/lstm_hidden_states
epochs:   0%|                                                                    | 0/1 [00:02<?, ?it/s, loss=3.45, lr=0.000305](tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0.],                                                         | 2/90 [00:02<01:34,  1.07s/it, total_it=2]
         [0., 1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 1.]],

        [[1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 1.]]], device='cuda:0'),)
```

## normal output

```
(tensor([[[ 8.7334e-01, -4.8659e-01,  2.2528e-02,  6.4885e+03],
         [ 4.8635e-01,  8.7363e-01,  1.5527e-02, -4.6202e+03],
         [-2.7237e-02, -2.6037e-03,  9.9963e-01, -6.3445e+01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]],

        [[ 8.7334e-01, -4.8659e-01,  2.2528e-02,  6.4885e+03],
         [ 4.8635e-01,  8.7363e-01,  1.5527e-02, -4.6202e+03],
         [-2.7237e-02, -2.6037e-03,  9.9963e-01, -6.3445e+01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]]],
       device='cuda:0'),)
saving hidden-state image hc_state_14_32_08_581169.png to ../../visual_result/lstm_hidden_states
epochs:   0%|                                                                      | 0/1 [00:01<?, ?it/s, loss=3.94, lr=0.0003]tensor([ 8.7283e-01,  4.8730e-01, -2.6772e-02, -3.4203e+03], device='cuda:0')       | 1/90 [00:01<01:47,  1.20s/it, total_it=1]
(tensor([[[ 8.7283e-01, -4.8751e-01,  2.2528e-02,  6.4922e+03],
         [ 4.8730e-01,  8.7312e-01,  1.4569e-02, -4.6133e+03],
         [-2.6772e-02, -1.7379e-03,  9.9964e-01, -6.8084e+01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]],

        [[ 8.7235e-01, -4.8834e-01,  2.3104e-02,  6.4954e+03],
         [ 4.8815e-01,  8.7265e-01,  1.3706e-02, -4.6071e+03],
         [-2.6854e-02, -6.7833e-04,  9.9964e-01, -7.5985e+01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]]],
       device='cuda:0'),)
saving hidden-state image hc_state_14_32_09_748923.png to ../../visual_result/lstm_hidden_states
epochs:   0%|                                                                    | 0/1 [00:02<?, ?it/s, loss=3.63, lr=0.000305]tensor([ 8.7182e-01,  4.8909e-01, -2.6878e-02, -3.4184e+03], device='cuda:0')       | 2/90 [00:02<01:32,  1.05s/it, total_it=2]
(tensor([[[ 8.7182e-01, -4.8925e-01,  2.3774e-02,  6.4990e+03],
         [ 4.8909e-01,  8.7214e-01,  1.2556e-02, -4.6002e+03],
         [-2.6878e-02,  6.8170e-04,  9.9964e-01, -8.5845e+01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]],

        [[ 8.7129e-01, -4.9016e-01,  2.4445e-02,  6.5026e+03],
         [ 4.9002e-01,  8.7163e-01,  1.1885e-02, -4.5933e+03],
         [-2.7133e-02,  1.6239e-03,  9.9963e-01, -9.3492e+01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]]],
       device='cuda:0'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `torch.inverse` with [this inverse function](https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.2/_modules/torchgeometry/core/transformations.html#inverse_transformation) from  [pytorch geometry](https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.2/transformations.html). The problem is bypassed, still wondering why it occurred though.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you use cuda version of tensor. If you do matrix inverse operation under cuda, it will always return an identity matrix. Detach to cpu would solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).